# How to apply a mask to a texture with transparency to achieve see-trough effect

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm trying to apply a mask to a texture with transparency. The effect I'm trying to achieve is an object with a crack, and you should be able to see trough the crack. I tried using blending and frame buffers with no success.

Here are the sprites I'm using:
The ball: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gImO.png
(notice that the ball is transparent around)
The mask: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4Uw.png
(the mask is white with transparent cracks in the middle)

This is the current result I'm getting:
[image]
This is the result I'm looking for:
[image]
(this was done using pixmaps by checking each pixel in the mask, and drawing only those with alpha > 0, but it is too slow, it freezes for a second or two on android, and I can't preload it because I don't know the object I'm applying the mask to until I need to apply it)

This is my render function:

```
@Override
public void render() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  batch.begin();

  mBackground.draw(batch);

  batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ZERO, GL20.GL_SRC_COLOR);
  mMask.draw(batch);

  batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_DST_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA);
  mObject.draw(batch);

  batch.end();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to provide a customized shader in libgdx? If so, create a shader that samples from the mask texture and also the sphere tex so that the mask is applied in the fragment shader... This means that the sampling of your mask texture would have to align well with the UVs of your sphere mesh... If that's a non-starter, another approach could be to do a pre-pass that marks the stencil buffer where the crack is located (the shader here would need to discard white fragments), then use the stencil buffer to mask the subsequent renderables... Just some ideas- I'm not familiar with libgdx.

Comment: Another option, which may not be scalable for your problem, is to have two versions of each of the textures that need to be cracked... One with a crack and one without.

Comment: This is a job for texture combiners, really. But I try not to explain those nasty old things unless absolutely necessary. Shaders are ideal, but this looks like ES 1.x level stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get it working using shaders. One issue however, how can I position and rotate the mask? I want the mask to be at the same position and angle as the ball, but that is not possible because I can't rotate the mask Texture, I need to draw it in order to rotate it. The way I'm doing it right now is: bind the ball texture, bind the mask texture, draw the ball at a chosen position and at the chosen angle, then the shader fragment will receive both textures and will only draw a pixel if the pixels from both textures are not transparent.

Comment: Ok so the mask seems to move and rotate automatically, the problem is that I'm using a texture atlas, and my guess is that the mask is aligned with the atlas and not the texture region from the atlas. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get this working by using shaders. Here is my solution:
The render function:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    mBackground.draw(batch);

    batch.setShader(mShaderProgram);

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    mObjectTexture.bind(0);
    mShaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    mMaskTexture.bind(1);
    mShaderProgram.setUniformi("u_mask", 1);

    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    batch.draw(mObjectTexture, 0, 0, 500, 500);

    batch.end();
    batch.setShader(null);
}
```

The vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main() {
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_mask;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);
    vec4 maskColor = texture2D(u_mask, v_texCoords);

    gl_FragColor = texColor * maskColor.a;
}
```